# CoreData crash "Can't get value for 'batch' in bindings { }." when resetting NSManagedObjectContext

Tags: core-data

I'm using [JSQCoreDataKit](https://github.com/jessesquires/JSQCoreDataKit) for setting up Core Data stack.

My setup includes two CoreData stacks, one backed by SQLite database, the second in-memory only.

In my app, during log out, I'm resetting both stacks - see the code: https://github.com/jessesquires/JSQCoreDataKit/blob/develop/Source/CoreDataStack.swift#L142

When resetting the in-memory core data stack, my app *sometimes* crashes on a line where the main NSManagedObjectContext is being reset. I haven't been able to reproduce it locally.

The crash message itself is something that Google doesn't find any results for:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Can't get value for 'batch' in bindings {
}.'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010dd3312b __exceptionPreprocess + 171
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010cd6bf41 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   Foundation                          0x000000010898b3de -[NSComparisonPredicate rightExpression] + 0
    3   Foundation                          0x000000010898c11f -[NSComparisonPredicate evaluateWithObject:substitutionVariables:] + 274
    4   CoreData                            0x000000010d769a08 -[NSDictionaryStoreMap handleFetchRequest:] + 504
    5   CoreData                            0x000000010d768bf3 -[NSMappedObjectStore executeFetchRequest:withContext:] + 243
    6   CoreData                            0x000000010d768a91 -[NSMappedObjectStore executeRequest:withContext:error:] + 193
    7   CoreData                            0x000000010d80c08b __65-[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator executeRequest:withContext:error:]_block_invoke + 1691
    8   CoreData                            0x000000010d8044a6 __55-[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator _routeHeavyweightBlock:]_block_invoke + 86
    9   CoreData                            0x000000010d818519 gutsOfBlockToNSPersistentStoreCoordinatorPerform + 201
    10  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000110fcb33d _dispatch_client_callout + 8
    11  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000110fd2235 _dispatch_queue_barrier_sync_invoke_and_complete + 392
    12  CoreData                            0x000000010d803e35 _perform + 213
    13  CoreData                            0x000000010d8041bb -[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator _routeHeavyweightBlock:] + 283
    14  CoreData                            0x000000010d70aac4 -[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator executeRequest:withContext:error:] + 660
    15  CoreData                            0x000000010d7090e4 -[NSManagedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:error:] + 564
    16  CoreData                            0x000000010d78794a _faultBatchAtIndex + 714
    17  CoreData                            0x000000010d789a4a -[_PFBatchFaultingArray retainedObjectAtIndex:] + 74
    18  CoreData                            0x000000010d789b32 -[_PFBatchFaultingArray objectAtIndex:] + 50
    19  CoreData                            0x000000010d8a2318 __72-[NSFetchedResultsController(PrivateMethods) _computeSectionInfo:error:]_block_invoke + 200
    20  CoreData                            0x000000010d74c748 developerSubmittedBlockToNSManagedObjectContextPerform + 168
    21  CoreData                            0x000000010d74c61f -[NSManagedObjectContext performBlockAndWait:] + 239
    22  CoreData                            0x000000010d8a1e03 -[NSFetchedResultsController(PrivateMethods) _computeSectionInfo:error:] + 691
    23  CoreData                            0x000000010d8a665b __82-[NSFetchedResultsController(PrivateMethods) _core_managedObjectContextDidChange:]_block_invoke + 1083
    24  CoreData                            0x000000010d74c748 developerSubmittedBlockToNSManagedObjectContextPerform + 168
    25  CoreData                            0x000000010d74c61f -[NSManagedObjectContext performBlockAndWait:] + 239
    26  CoreData                            0x000000010d8a6207 -[NSFetchedResultsController(PrivateMethods) _core_managedObjectContextDidChange:] + 119
    27  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010dcceeac __CFNOTIFICATIONCENTER_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER__ + 12
    28  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010dccedaa _CFXRegistrationPost + 442
    29  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010dcceaf2 ___CFXNotificationPost_block_invoke + 50
    30  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010dc90792 -[_CFXNotificationRegistrar find:object:observer:enumerator:] + 1826
    31  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010dc8f90c _CFXNotificationPost + 652
    32  Foundation                          0x00000001089548f2 -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] + 66
    33  CoreData                            0x000000010d735725 -[NSManagedObjectContext(_NSInternalNotificationHandling) _postObjectsDidChangeNotificationWithUserInfo:] + 773
    34  CoreData                            0x000000010d7cdedf -[NSManagedObjectContext reset] + 1119
    35  JSQCoreDataKit                      0x000000010906b3c8 _T014JSQCoreDataKit04CoreB5StackC5resetySo13DispatchQueueC02onH0_yAA0E6ResultOc10completiontFyycfU_ + 88
    36  JSQCoreDataKit                      0x000000010906b3ec _T014JSQCoreDataKit04CoreB5StackC5resetySo13DispatchQueueC02onH0_yAA0E6ResultOc10completiontFyycfU_TA + 12
    37  JSQCoreDataKit                      0x0000000109065599 _T0Ix_IyB_TR + 41
    38  CoreData                            0x000000010d74c748 developerSubmittedBlockToNSManagedObjectContextPerform + 168
    39  CoreData                            0x000000010d74c61f -[NSManagedObjectContext performBlockAndWait:] + 239
    40  JSQCoreDataKit                      0x000000010906ae2d _T014JSQCoreDataKit04CoreB5StackC5resetySo13DispatchQueueC02onH0_yAA0E6ResultOc10completiontF + 317
    41  MyApp                            0x000000010c4f362a _T08MyApp14DataRepositoryV09resetCoreD5Stackyyyc10completion_tFZyAA19AsyncBlockOperationCcfU0_ + 106
    42  MyApp                            0x000000010c717761 _T08MyApp19AsyncBlockOperationC5startyyF + 433
    43  MyApp                            0x000000010c7177c4 _T08MyApp19AsyncBlockOperationC5startyyFTo + 36
    44  Foundation                          0x0000000108983577 __NSOQSchedule_f + 369
    45  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000110fcb33d _dispatch_client_callout + 8
    46  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000110fd65f9 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 628
    47  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010dcf5e39 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 9
    48  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010dcba462 __CFRunLoopRun + 2402
    49  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010dcb9889 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 409
    50  GraphicsServices                    0x0000000112dfc9c6 GSEventRunModal + 62
    51  UIKit                               0x000000010a0875d6 UIApplicationMain + 159
    52  GoOut                               0x00000001061e3857 main + 55
    53  libdyld.dylib                       0x0000000111047d81 start + 1
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## The possible root cause

As [Tom Harrington](https://stackoverflow.com/users/43832/tom-harrington) points out in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49054349/1161723), it's one particular instance of `NSFetchedResultsController` that gets notified when the main context is being reset and probably tries to perform a fetch that fails, resulting in an exception being thrown.

Interestingly, this happens only when the in-memory store is used. When switching to SQLite store, the problem goes away. Since I want to keep using the in-memory store for performance reasons, I came up with the following workaround.

## The workaround

To prevent the `NSFetchedResultsController` from crashing, I make the FRC stop observing changes in the context just before the context (and whole CoreData stack) is reset.

This is done by posting a notification from a method where the CoreData stack is being reset and setting the FRC's delegate to `nil`. The following code is from the ViewController where this particular FRC is used.

```
private func setupObservers() {
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(
        self,
        selector: #selector(didReceiveDataRepositoryWillResetNotification(_:)),
        name: Notification.Name.DataRepository.WillResetCoreData,
        object: nil
    )
}

@objc private func didReceiveDataRepositoryWillResetNotification(_ notification: Notification) {
    // HAX: Workaround for FRC throwing an exception when linked to a context backed by in-memory store
    // More info: https://stackoverflow.com/q/49052482/1161723
    fetchedResultsController?.delegate = nil
}
```

Note that I don't set the FRC's delegate property again anywhere as the whole UIViewController stack including the FRC is deallocated on logout anyway.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to be certain, but the stack trace offers a clue. Here's where you reset the context:

```
34  CoreData                            0x000000010d7cdedf -[NSManagedObjectContext reset] + 1119
```

A few levels deeper, this happens:

```
26  CoreData                            0x000000010d8a6207 -[NSFetchedResultsController(PrivateMethods) _core_managedObjectContextDidChange:] + 119
```

That's followed by other fetched results controller stuff, including things like

```
22  CoreData                            0x000000010d8a1e03 -[NSFetchedResultsController(PrivateMethods) _computeSectionInfo:error:] + 691
```

What this suggests is that you're resetting the context while an `NSFetchedResultsController` is still trying to keep your UI up to date. It notices changes caused by the reset and tries to handle those changes, but since a reset is in progress, this fails.

This is probably an example of why `reset` is hard to use safely. If you have any objects that use or reference a context in any way, a `reset` is likely to cause trouble. You probably need to make sure that whatever UI is using the `NSFetchedResultsController` is completely out of memory before calling `reset`.

Comment: Thank you, Tom. I've found the particular NSFetchedResultController from the stack trace and I'm able to reproduce the crash now. The funny thing is that when I switch from in-memory store to the sqlite, everything works as expected, no crashes.

Comment: It's probably a race condition that depends on how long it takes for each context to reset. The internals of the two must be very different.